# Connecting git branches with no shared history on Github

Tags: git, github

When creating a new repository on Github, I made the mistake of pushing a branch ORIGINAL that I did not want as the default branch first. My goal is to make a pull request from this branch into an empty master branch. My route to attempt to resolve this has been rather circuitous, as I am learning as I go:

1. Created a master branch in the Github UI, which branched from ORIGINAL. This was all wrong because I needed an empty master branch.
2. Created a new orphan branch named master and force pushed it to Github, then set master as the default branch. I was unable to make a pull request because of totally unrelated history between ORIGINAL and this orphaned master. I get the text "
   There isn’t anything to compare.
   master and ORIGINAL are entirely different commit histories."
   in the Github UI.
3. Created an orphaned master branch, created a branch off of it, NEW, and cherry-picked commits from ORIGINAL onto NEW. I then renamed ORGINAL to ORIGINAL-unconnected, renamed NEW to ORIGINAL, and force pushed master and ORIGINAL to overwrite what I had previously. I am still unable to create a pull request because of completely unrelated commit histories.

> ```
> * 74f259d (origin/ORIGINAL, ORIGINAL) Changes-2
> | * 2a64361 (origin/master, master) Initial commit
> | * bd2b261 (HEAD -> SECONDARY) Changes-3
> | * 7fcbf80 Changes-2
> |/
> * cb9e481 Changes-1
> * 58e742a Create project
> * 106d156 Initial commit
> * 6a063bb (ORIGINAL-unconnected) Changes-2
> | * 85a8896 (SECONDARY-unconnected) Changes-3
> | * 8f8a64b Changes-2
> |/
> * 5f0f295 Changes-1
> * 5566377 Create project
> ```

Are the histories unrelated in both my local copy and on Github, or only on Github? What would be an effective way to resolve my issue?

Comment: Can you post a diagram of your git history?

Comment: `git reset --hard origin/ORIGINAL` This will reset your local branch to have a track of your origin branch.