# Repo has multiple unconnected commits with no shared history

Tags: git

I'm working on a project that was run by a solo dev who had the habit of blowing out the entire working directory when he was ready to release a new version. I believe he had multiple repos that he was working off of and branch into master(github, bitbucket, &c.) and so the commit history shows a lot of commit chains without links between them.

I'm trying to debug and I can't do a direct diff between these independent chains without manually specifying commit hashes and it's very cumbersome. I'd like to link these branches/tags together, but I'm not sure the best approach. Some of these splits are weeks back and I want to keep the merges back in the commit history where they belong.

```
*     v2 release
|
*     commit
|
*     fresh/rebased

*     v1 merge/release
| \
| *   commit
| |
| *   commit
| 
*     fresh
```

I just want to be able to checkout the current master and be able to look back through the commit history and see where certain changes were made, so I'm guessing I need to do an ours strategy merge from the v2 branch to the v1 and set the timestamp manually?

Similar question here w/ no answer: [Connecting git branches with no shared history on Github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48906767/connecting-git-branches-with-no-shared-history-on-github)

Comment: "I can't do a direct diff between these independent chains without manually specifying commit hashes" - that doesn't make sense to me.  There must be refs on the older commit chains; why can you not use expressions relative to those?  Maybe I'm not understanding what you're trying to do, but in general `git diff` shouldn't care about if/how two commits are historically related

Comment: It would be helpful to others, if you add the steps what you are doing and what you are trying to achieve? How are you doing the diff? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no real right-answer here, but there are two or three options.  Most start with `git replace`: use `git replace --graft` to graft the histories together.  But there are some drawbacks, and that's where the options come in.

## Long

The fundamental issue is that these commits already exist and cannot be changed.  That won't ever go away, but you have the ability to use *different* commits.  The tricky parts are deciding *how* to do that, and whether to make everyone switch.

There is a best way to get started (in my opinion anyway), which is to use `git replace`.  This means you need to know what `git replace` really does.  That starts with this notion: *Every object in Git is represented by a hash ID.*

#### Hash IDs and the commit graph

You already know something about these hash IDs, as you're using them now to do your `git diff`s.  We also have the fact that branch and tag *names* just store one single hash ID.  For a branch name, that hash ID is the commit that Git should treat as the *tip of the branch*.

Each commit itself, having been found by some hash ID, contains another hash ID—well, usually *one*, but sometimes more, and rarely, none.  For instance:

```
$ git cat-file -p HEAD | sed 's/@/ /'
tree 1fd4a47af4942cbdee0bdcb4375612ab521a4a51
parent 5571d085b3c9c2aa9470a10bcf2b8518d3e4ec99
author Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com> 1531941857 -0700
committer Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com> 1531941857 -0700

Third batch for 2.19 cycle

Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com>
```

This commit—`b7bd9486b055c3f967a870311e704e3bb0654e4f`—has, as its parent, commit `5571d085b3c9c2aa9470a10bcf2b8518d3e4ec99`.  We say that the branch name *points to* the tip commit, and the tip commit *points to* its parent:

```
... <-grandparent <-parent <-tip   <--branch
```

and as long as the connections are linear, we get a nice simple history of commits.  If there is a branch in the history, we have two tips, with two names:

```
A--B--C   <-- master (HEAD)
    \
     D--E   <-- develop
```

with both `C` and `D` pointing back to `B`.

Commit `A` is a *root commit:* it has no parent.  In a typical repository you have just one root commit, but it's not too difficult—as you have found!—for someone to create multiple root commits.

When Git is walking history, you tell it to start at some commit—usually a branch tip—and Git works backwards, following all the chains.  A *merge* commit brings two branches together, so that when going *backwards*, it causes Git to branch out its walk!  That is, if we merge `develop` back into `master`:

```
A--B--C---F   <-- master (HEAD)
    \    /
     D--E   <-- develop
```

and then have Git start at commit `F` and work backwards, Git goes: `F`, (`C`, `E`, and `D` in some order), `B`, and `A`.  Upon reaching `A`, which has no parent, Git stops.

(More precisely, `git log` has a *priority queue* of commits to show.  Git starts out by putting whatever commit or commits you name on the command line, or `HEAD` if you don't name anything, into the queue.  Then `git log` takes one commit out of the queue and, if it's supposed to be shown, shows it.  Git then puts that commit's parents into the queue.  This repeats until the queue is empty.  The order in which commits are visited depends on log options, and there is an option to suppress all but first-parent insertion as well.)

#### Replacements

All of the above—in fact everything else, too—works by hash ID: Git starts out with the notion that `master` means the hash ID of commit `F`, or whatever, so it puts that hash ID into the list of things to look at.  Then Git grabs that object from the database, and this is where replacements come in.

The objects themselves *cannot be changed*, so commit `A` is just commit `A`—but we can have Git "avert its eyes", so to speak.  If we don't *like* commit `A` for some reason—for instance, it should have a parent commit—we can make a *replacement* for it and tell Git:

> Whenever you are about to look at commit `A`, look at `A'` instead

We do this with `git replace`.  The `--graft` option tells `git replace` to copy the original `A` but put in some different parent(s), so if we have:

```
A--B--C   <-- new

D--E--F   <-- old
```

and `A` really should be joined up to `F`, we can make a new `A'` that's otherwise just *like* `A`, but links to `F`:

```
        A--B--C   <--new

        A'
       /
D--E--F   <-- old
```

and now have `git log` scan from `C` to `B`, to *replacement* `A'`, to `F`.  Running `git log` now makes it *look like* the history goes `D-E-F-A'-B-C`.

#### Hiding replacements

Sometimes you might want to see the original, unreplaced chains.  Using `git --no-replace-objects log`, you will see what's actually in the graph without the replacements.

#### The main flaw with replacements

The main problem with using `git replace` is that these replacement objects are not *cloned* by default.  A new clone of the repository with the replacement `A'` does not have `A'`.  To clone replacements, you can add a directive to your `fetch` configuration.

Replacements can be made permanent by re-copying the history, using `git filter-branch`.  This step is a bit drastic since it means everyone must switch from the old repository to the new one.

#### Alternatively, you can just merge the unrelated histories

You don't *have* to rewrite or replace history, if you don't mind odd graph constructs and tricky diffs.  You can simply add a merge that ignores the other input, using `git merge -s ours`.  For instance, given:

```
A--B--C   <-- new

 D--E--F   <-- old
```

you can run `git checkout new; git merge -s ours old` to get:

```
A--B--C--G   <-- new
        /
 D--E--F   <-- old
```

where the two parents of `G` are `C` and `F`, but the snapshot in `G` is exactly the same as that in `C`.  This simply adds on to the existing repository, so it has none of the replacement and/or filter-branch drawbacks.  The problem is that commits `A-B-C` are still not properly related to `D-E-F`.  If that's not a big deal, that may be your best approach.